# System Admin Perspective about Developer using Angular JS

Tags: asp.net, angular, security, iis

This was all requested by a developer in the company I work for in order for the developer to have a publicly available web app for use by the company employees.

I set up a public web server (using a third party host) running Debian/Nginx where we host an angular js app as the front-end. 
He needed the back-end to connect to our internal SQL server. 
He wrote the back-end using ASP.Net.
I put the ASP.Net code on an IIS server in our DMZ, allowing SQL only access from the DMZ server to the internal SQL server service.
I setup the corporate firewall to only allow access from the Public web server IP (mentioned above) to the public IP of the back-end IIS website (running on the DMZ) so that nothing else would see that public IIS website as existing.
The Angular JS app running on the 3rd party hosted public facing site, connects to the non public facing IIS website to request data and displays it to the end user in the browser.

Problem is this whole thing doesn't work without the end user having access to the non public facing IIS website.

I was under the impression that the front-end Angular JS site would request its data, manipulate and then display it to the end user. So that the end user only needed to be able to access the publicly available website.

He is telling me that this is not possible with Angular JS.

This is what he told me specifically;

*"So my understanding now is that when this angular app starts up it's really just one traditional web page (index.html for instance) then the whole app runs as typescript in the browser except for image files and other assets. It's the typescript on the clients PC that makes the request to the API server for data, not the Linux server as you would expect in a traditional web server app."*

In years past we had this exact setup using ASP.net on both ends. The DMZ back-end server was never exposed to the public. I'm not a developer but I'm security conscious and cannot endorse opening up the IIS website to the public.

Am I wrong about this? Is there no way he can use Angular JS to grab the data from a back-end and manipulate/display it without the end user needing access to the back-end server?

Sorry about how long this question is, I wanted to make sure to include detailed information.

Comment: "we had this exact setup using ASP.net on both ends." That's the major difference between ASP.NET and Angular.

Comment: So what he's saying about Angular not being able to do that is correct?

Comment: Yes, and no. Your API can call other APIs, so the Angular server (Not AngularJs, as typescript is Angular 2+) serves typescript / html / css/ images compiled to JS / CSS, HTML etc to the client. The client can call the Angular web server, to request it to act as middle ware and call your internal services / Db.

Comment: 2nd comment, and more useful maybe: This is going to be closed as off topic, seeing as how it's about IS, more than code. there should however be a stack site for sysadmins / networking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular and AngularJS are **frontend** frameworks, meaning the api calls made from the angular app, origin in the client browser. If you need that the calls to your ASP.Net backend come only from the linux server hosting your frontend, then you need to have some kind of backend on that host that proxies calls from the clients to the ASP.Net backend. I think that's not hard to achieve using Node.js (personal preference), but you could go with whatever you can manage to run on your linux hosting.